# Can't seem to find element with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm a new coder, and i've recently gotten into web scraping and automation. I'm trying to make a program that will Log In on a trading platform, and search for the stock Facebook "FB"

The Log In part seems to be working fine, but the searching for FB stock isn't. The automation process won't type anything in the search bar. I i've tried all the (find_element_by) methods that i know of, but it still wont work.

The account details will be in the program, if you want to run the code yourself "FEEL FREE!" it's a fake account...

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/larskvist/downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.forex.com/en-uk/account-login/')

username_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Username')
username_elem.send_keys('kebababdulaziz@gmail.com')

time.sleep(0.5)

password_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Password')
password_elem.send_keys('KEbababdulaziz')
password_elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(5)

search_elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('market-search__button ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched')
search_elem.send_keys('FB')

time.sleep(30)
browser.close()
```

This is the element i wan't to get:

```
<input _ngcontent-c23="" appcustomplaceholder="" class="market-search__search-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="query" type="text" placeholder="Search markets">
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have target wrong element.You should target `input` element.

To avoid `sleep()` which unnecessary slow down your script it is best practice to Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector.

```
search_elem = WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.market-search__search-input")))
search_elem.send_keys('FB')
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the search part works. I'm having some issues with the fact that i think the whole process is too fast so that the search element makes recommendations to press. But i think i need to study the package more to get an understanding of why that has happened.
THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
search_elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('market-search__button)
```

Instead of using the full class name with spaces between them...

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working... I've inserted the search_elem like you wrote, and got this error after the site had logged in but not typed anything into the search bar. 
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable